# node express app.use case and mongo databases

Tags: express

I am trying to build a simple express app with a mongodb database. Here are some lines of code that I am a bit confused about:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');


// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

So I am using monk to communicate with my database that is running on localhost:27017. That I get.

What is the app.use doing? I read this explanation:

> We already defined "db" when we added Mongo and Monk to app.js. It's
>   our Monk connection object. By adding this function to app.use, we're
>   adding that object to every HTTP request (ie: "req") our app makes.
>   Note: this is probably sub-optimal for performance but, again, we're
>   going quick-n-dirty here.

What does this mean? What are some http requests that I can make?

It seems to allow me to do something like this in a routes file:

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

So I guess when my router makes a get request to /userlist... I have access to the request and response variables. That request variable has a db attached to it? What are the request and response variables?

-Jeff

Answer (score 2):

Express uses something called a chain of responsibility. Basically, every **HTTP request** coming into the application goes through **all the handlers** registered with `app.use`, `app.get`, or similar. They are executed in the order they were registered, and only the handlers matching the request URL are selected.

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});
```

This means that the above code registers a handler that:

- is always executed, *for every request* (since there is no URL specified)
- executes *first* (because it's registered before anything else)
- stores a reference to your database in `req.db` (on the object representing the HTTP request)
- calls `next()` which does exactly what it says - let's the *next* handler handle the request

The next handler in that case will be one of the "real" handlers that produce responses, and since your DB handler executed first, the `req.db` reference will already be available.